# How to send email by Page onLoad when the user enters to this page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a new ASP.NET developer and I could be able to send email by the web application that I am working on it. Now, I want to create a page that when the user opens it, it will send email automatically. How to do that?

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can add some code to your Web.Config. In my example I'm using gmail server. Knowing the settings of your server you can easy change it.

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="youraddress@gmail.com" deliveryMethod="Network">
      <network userName="youraddress@gmail.com" 
               password="yourrealpassword" 
               host="smtp.gmail.com" 
               defaultCredentials="false" 
               port="587"
               enableSsl="true" />
      </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Secondly you can modify your pageload event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    mailMessage.To.Add("real@address.com");
    mailMessage.Subject = "Some subject";
    mailMessage.Body = "Some text";

    using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
    {
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) class to send an email. The documentation contains an example of its usage.

Comment: I am using it. What I want is to send emails when the user opens a certain onLoad page

Comment: @user1093651, great, then put the code that you already have to send emails in the Page_Load method.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorials about [Use ASP.NET to Send Email from a Web Site](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-use-aspnet-to-send-email-from-a-web-site) and [Sending Email with ASP.NET](http://www.aspheute.com/english/20000918.asp)